# Нужна ли возможность настройка приоритета для sitemap

Tags: sitemap

Здравствуйте, тут я думаю нужна ли клиенту вставить функцию где он будет настраивать приоритет(от 0.1 до 1) для каждого поста? Вообще нужна ли она вообще, важно ли это или нет?

Просто думаю, если я поставлю приоритета 0.5 для всех постов, а потом клиент вдруг узнает что такое приоритет и заставит меня сделать настройку для каждого, он такой продвинутый клиент у меня.

Comment: `priority` в общем-то необязательный параметр. И используют его очень редко. Если очень хочется вставить `priority` в свой sitemap - выставляйте 1 для главной, 0.9 для товаров, 0.8 для остальных страниц - в моей практике работы с СЕО-специалистами это самая популярная комбинация. Выставлять же приоритет для каждой страницы вручную адекватный человек не будет.

Comment: @Равнодушный, спасибо коротко и ясно!

Comment: З.Ы. Ради повсеместного `0.5` `priority` точно не нужен - лишняя трата трафика.

Answer (score 1):

проще проставлять автоматически (1 страница - 1, 2уровень - 0.9, 3уровень 0.8 ...), если конечно сайт из 10 страниц.

Comment: на сайте очень много страницы больше 100, и постов еще больше